# Virt-Manager, QEMU/KVM, "paused" VM still uses CPU?

Tags: virt-manager

I "paused" the VM. If I understood it correctly, it is like "sleep" mode of a real computer. But in the performance tab,the VM's CPU usage is always about 2%~4% and never goes down to 0. How come it's not 0%?

[image]

Comment: Probably because of some kernel threads that must not be suspended. Can you run top or htop on host ?

Comment: I can run htop, but I'm not sure what I am supposed to see. The command that is using 13% CPU is a white qemu-system-x86_64 with long arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The graphs are showing the CPU usage of the whole VM process. When the VM is paused, the emulated VM CPUs are stopped, but the whole emulator binary on the host is still running and consuming CPU time, libvirt is actively communicating with it, etc.

If you `top` on the host you'll see a qemu binary still using CPU. That's what the graphs are showing